# WebSocket video MP4 stream, save video and make snapshot

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

There is a WebSocket server, wss://stoa-wsez-e01.ezvds.net/ezs/60/ezugi_5_hd/websocketstream2. If you connect to it, for example, here at https://piehost.com/websocket-tester and send `{"eventType":"PLAY","stream":"ezugi_5_hd","requestId":0}`, messages with the stream will be received.

Let's imagine Node.js connects, takes a screenshot, and disconnects.

I tried something like this:

```
const videoPath = path.join(outputDirectory, `video_${timestamp}.webm`);
const videoStream = fs.createWriteStream(videoPath);


ws.on('message', (data: Buffer) => {
  videoStream.write(data);
});

ws.on('close', () => {
  videoStream.end();
  ffmpeg(videoPath)
    .output(path.join(outputDirectory, `screenshot_${timestamp}_%d.png`))
    .on('end', () => {
      fs.unlinkSync(videoPath);
    })
    .run();
});
```

The saved video files cannot be opened, and ffmpeg gives an error:

```
video_1704549199939.webm: Invalid data found when processing input.
```

So clearly, I'm doing something wrong.

**UPD**
In general, I am confident that I can take a snapshot from the video. The problem is how to capture and save this video to the disk. That's where I need help.

Answer (score 1):

You're undoubtedly not getting enough data from the server in a single message to take a screenshot.  You're also not getting WebM data, but an MP4.  (And, you should really be putting this data in your question as you'll undoubtedly solve the problem at some point and then your question won't be useful to others.)

Some recommendations:

- Your server needs to stream data back to you and not just send some small arbitrary-sized chunk.
- Your client (the Node.js app that's receiving this data) needs to start an FFmpeg process to read from STDIN, and then pipe that data to FFmpeg.
- Only FFmpeg can tell you when it has enough data to stop.  Once FFmpeg exits, read its exit code to determine if the thumbnail generation was successful.

You might also consider simply not using Web Sockets at all.  You're basically just making a GET request, so there doesn't appear to be any reason.  If you can handle a normal HTTP request on the server end, FFmpeg can actually just connect to the URL directly and dump its thumbnail.  Then your app just needs to execute FFmpeg.  Simpler, less error-prone, and you don't need to invent your own protocol to get it done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. He will help me advance. Important - the websocket server is not mine. I just need to make a short recording of someone else's stream. And then take a screenshot of it.

Comment: And it's important, a small code snippet is provided. I'm not trying to do it after the first message; I receive them for a few seconds and then save the file. In terms of size, it seems to be correct, but apparently some headers are missing, and the file does not open.

Comment: @AleksandrRogonov I only received ~8 KB from that server when I connected, which surely is not enough to decode the video.

Comment: Did you send the message `{"eventType":"PLAY","stream":"ezugi_5_hd","requestId":0}` after connecting?

Comment: @AleksandrRogonov Yes

Comment: They may not work with US IP addresses. This is a regulated industry (Gambling). Thanks for your attempt to help.